# How to add naked domain (without www) on GoDaddy deployed via Heroku?

Tags: dns, godaddy, cname, domain-forwarding, heroku

I have a domain that's been deployed via Heroku, and is up and running fine with the www. But if I go to the domain without the www, it does not render correctly. I tried adding both domains on Heroku, with www and without www, but unfortunately it still does not work.

Also, I tried following step two on [here](http://documentation.unbounce.com/hc/en-us/articles/203687274-Setting-Up-Your-CNAME-with-GoDaddy-godaddy-com-) but continued to get an error: `An unexpected error occurred. If this issue continues, contact support.`

How can I add a naked domain to GoDaddy to forward to my web deployed on Heroku like my domain with www?

**First Description** GoDaddy (Only manually added the Heroku URL to CNAME www and Domain Forward to Heroku URL).

**Second Description** DNS Target set to Heroku URL and Domain on Heroku (Have one row for www and other without www).

Comment: Can you post an example of what you DNS settings look like??

Comment: @closetnoc Sure thing, on GoDaddy or Heroku?

Comment: I am not sure how your domain is set up, so if it is set-up on GoDaddy, that is a starting place. For the record, I have no clue about Heroku. I did go to the site to see what web server was being used and somehow, I did not see it. If it is Apache, I may be able to help there too. At least, I can see what you can see and perhaps something will jump out at me. If I have not clue, then perhaps someone will. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Definitely. So stackexchange currently isn't allowing me to post images so I will just post the links here. Please refer back to the original post for descriptions. First description: http://i.stack.imgur.com/INXIO.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/y7OS7.png and Second description: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KMeEb.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/ol71G.png Images are cut off just to hide vital info.

Comment: Okay. The DNS looks okay at first blush. The rest I have no idea about. Have you call their tech support?

Comment: Have you considered a redirect of example.com to www.example.com. I know it might not be the best but it will work.

Comment: @norcaljohnny don't think I have yet. sorry but how so?

Comment: @LyManeug see posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways. Either use URL forwarding or you can use a redirect in your `.htaccess` file. Try URL forwarding first.

**URL Forwarding**

To get this to work, go to the GoDaddy domain information and set forwarding to www.example.com.

**.htaccess method**

```
RewriteEngine on 
#if host ==domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
#and uri==/mypage
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mypage
#redirect the request to http://app-heroku.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://app-heroku.com [P]
```

This will force people who do not use the non-www to the www.

**Depending on your hosting (cpanel/plesk) Here are the steps.** godaddy.com/help/redirect-urls-with-your-hosting-account-512‌​0

Comment: Appreciate the answer but are you referring to the root folder in GoDaddy/Heroku or my project itself? Sorry, just haven't heard anything like this before. Is this some type of a hack/work around?

Comment: Try the URL forwarding in Godaddy first. Then if that does not work I will help you with the htaccess.

Comment: Sorry but could you guide me on how to do the forwarding? I believe I already have one set up for www Heroku on Godaddy

Comment: "I believe I already have one set up for www " that may also be why the non-www does not load right. But depending on your hosting (cpanel/plesk) Here is the steps. https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-urls-with-your-hosting-account-5120